# Finding a match in a list and displaying span using regex

Tags: python, regex

So I am trying to search through a list for this sequence of characters using regex

```
rbd = RVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNF
```

the regex I came up with is:

```
rbd = re.finditer(r"RV[NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH]{219}NF",seqs)
```

meaning that I am looking for a pattern that starts with "RV" followed by 219 characters consisting of the letters [NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH] and the pattern ends with the characters "NF"

my code is

```
import re

seqs = """>UDW38242.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAILMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
>UDW40541.1 |surface glycoprotein|TX|GenBank|ssRNA(+)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>UDW40565.1 |surface glycoprotein|TX|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLTTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAISGTNGTKRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNN
ATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYHKNNKSWMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQ
GNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLA
LHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTL
KSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVA
DYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNY
KLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGV
EGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTYGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNF
NGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIDDTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTN
TSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECD
IPIGAGICASYQTQTNSHRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPINFTISVT
TEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVFA
QVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKXXXXCLGD
IAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLXXXXXXXXIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMA
YRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQDVVNQNAQALNTLV
KQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILARLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASAN
LAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICH
DGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTHNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQP
ELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQEL
GKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEP
VLKGVKLHYT
>UDW49791.1 |surface glycoprotein|GA|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGVYFASTXXXXXXXXXIFGTTXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXIXXXXFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAH
>UDW51945.1 |surface glycoprotein|NC|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSVLEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAIDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYTFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTV
YDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESL
IDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFD
EDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT
"""

rbd = re.finditer(r'RV[NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH]{219,219}NF',seqs)

for n in rbd:

     print(n.group() + "->" + str(n.span()) + "\n")
```

but I cant seem to get an output, what am I doing wrong

Comment: Because of line breaks? Try `rbd = re.finditer(r'RV[NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH]{219,219}NF',seqs.replace("\n", ""))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have line breaks inside the string.

To fix the issue, you can remove the line breaks with

```py
rbd = re.finditer(r'RV[NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH]{219,219}NF',seqs.replace("\n", ""))
```

Or, you may remove any whitespace using

```py
rbd = re.finditer(r'RV[NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH]{219,219}NF', "".join(seqs.split()))
```